# X-Axis has alternate interval in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I am using Microsoft Chart , Spline chart type . And I have months on X-Axis but it shows alternate months 
ie; January , March, May....etc.
But I need to show it in continuation. Though it has marker which shows for each month so that means its getting the value(I am guessing).
My aspx is :

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" Height="500px" Width="1100px" ID="Chart3"  >
                    <Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Series1"  ChartType="Spline" MarkerStyle="Circle" MarkerColor="#0033CC" MarkerSize="15" BackGradientStyle="Center"></asp:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
```

Please let me know how to do it , I have checked the properties but found nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am using MVC so the fix for me was

```
<ChartArea>
  <AxisX Interval='1'>
</ChartArea>
```